# core-animated-pages in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I noticed that there is no substitute for `core-animated-pages` in Polymer 1.0 (there is no `iron-animated-pages`). Am I missing something? Is there any other way to implement similar functionality?
Any answer greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new component is named **neon-animated-pages** and is a part of **neon-animation**

Here is its documentation:
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages

and repository: https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation#page-transitions

> The animation-related elements that were part of core will be created as part of the neon product line.